# Joining the top result in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM HISTORY
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.CUST_NUMBER = HISTORY.CUST_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN ( 
    Select LOAN_DATE, CUST_NUMBER, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, STOCK_NUMBER, LOC_SALE
    From LOAN
    WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER != 'DD'
    ORDER BY LOAN_DATE DESC
    ) LOAN ON LOAN.CUST_NUMBER  = HISTORY.CUST_NUMBER
order by DATE desc
```

But I want only the top result from the loan table to be joined (Most recent by Loan_date). For some reason, it's getting three records (one for each loan on the customer I'm looking at). I'm sure I'm missing something simple?

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` if you want just the top result from the loan table?

Comment: Actually, I think that is part of my problem. I didn't realize, but I'm actually getting one result for each loan x one result for each history entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're after joining the latest loan row per cust_number, then this ought to do the trick:

```
select * 
from   history
       left join customer on customer.cust_number = history.cust_number
       left join (select loan_date,
                         cust_number,
                         account_number,
                         stock_number,
                         loc_sale
                  from   (select loan_date,
                                 cust_number,
                                 account_number,
                                 stock_number,
                                 loc_sale,
                                 row_number() over (partition by cust_number
                                                    order by loan_date desc) rn
                          from   loan
                          where account_number != 'DD')
                  where   rn = 1) loan on loan.cust_number  = history.cust_number
order by date desc;
```

If there are two rows with the same loan_date per cust_number and you want to retrieve both, then change the `row_number()` analytic function for `rank()`.

If you only want to retreive one row, then you'd have to make sure you add additional columns into the order by, to make sure that the tied rows always display in the same order, otherwise you could find that sometimes you get different rows returned on subsequent runs of the query.

Comment: It's just a little over my head, but it definitely got the result set I was looking for.

Comment: Analytic functions are awesome! If you've never come across them before, you should have a play with them. They're similar to aggregate queries, except that they don't collapse rows (eg. the `partition by` clause is equivalent to the aggregate `group by` clause). They allow you to access data in other rows and use it in the current row (so you can do cumulative sums, etc). In the query above, the `row_number()` assigns an incrementing number across all the rows grouped by cust_number, in the order of loan_date descending. So the row with latest loan_date = 1, the next row is 2, etc.

Comment: You can see the effect of the analytic function by taking that subquery on its own and running it. http://www.orafaq.com/node/55 is a page that I've found useful in coming to grips with them.